# JAVA_HOME command not found

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, java-home

I am trying to install a s/w using software center in Ubuntu(14.04).
It gives me the following error.

```
installArchives() failed: Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 2: JAVA_HOME: command not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
Error in function: 
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 2: JAVA_HOME: command not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
```

However, when I type `which java` or `echo "$JAVA_HOME"` in terminal it gives me:

```
/usr/bin/java
```

Moreover, the permissions of java(in /usr/bin/java) is as shown below:

```
owner: root

access:Read and write

group:root             
access:read-only

others:read-only

You are not the owner,so you cannot change these permissions.
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to install this package using sudo? Perhaps the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set for your personal user but not for the root user. When you install using sudo, you are effectively becoming the root user.

Comment: Please post the command you are using to install the software package.

Comment: Using Software Centre.

Comment: But when I type sudo echo $JAVA_HOME ,it shows the path as /usr/bin/java

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/environment`?

Comment: The content is:  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME ="/usr/lib/jvm/"